# is it possible to make spread operator ignore undefined propperties

Tags: javascript

Given the following

```
[{ a: 5, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 5 }].map(x => {
  return {
    ...x,
    b: undefined
  }
})
```

I would like to end up with something like

`[{a:5},{a:2})`

Is that possible?
I know I could do something like

```
[{ a: 5, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 5 }].map(x => {
const obj = {
    ...x,
  }
  delete obj.b
  return obj
})
```

or

```
[{ a: 5, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 5 }].map(x => {
  return {
    a: x.a
  }
})
```

The first method results in the values just being set to "undefined".
The second method seems wasteful for larger arrays as a new variable is created object, and also my typescript complains about it because the original property wasn't optional.
The third method works if you only want to retain a small number of properties, but once it gets over just a few properties it just seems unwieldy.
For my current case, I'll probably opt for the second method, but I am curious if there's a way to handle this more elegantly.

I'm aware that I can also do something like:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key])
```

But it still doesn't seem all that elegant.

Comment: rest parameter syntax can help in this case: destructure the properties you want to remove and collect rest of the properties using the rest parameter syntax. Something like: `arr.map(({ b, ...restProps }) => { ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ignore the `b` and collect all properties in `rest` and then spread the `rest` in the final result.

You can also make it one liner

```
const result = arr.map(({ b, ...rest }) => rest);
```

```js
const arr = [
  { a: 5, b: 2 },
  { a: 2, b: 5 },
]
const result = arr.map(({ b, ...rest }) => rest);

console.log(result);
```